# Create a split-circle label in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create a certain type of label common in the UK forestry sector. It consists of a circle with a horizontal dividing line, with one attribute in the upper portion and a second in the lower. I have concatenated the two parts of the label, with a newline character, and giving the label a circular border, but I can't work out how to add the horizontal dividing line.

I'm using the most recent edition of QGIS, Essen, in 64-bit windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS knows this as "text diagrams". They are in the [vector layer properties and can be found under text diagram](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#diagrams-menu)

[image: Text diagram]

Comment: That's brilliant - I'd not come across that feature before. Do you know of anyway they can be manually repositioned? I know that they can be set to x,y coordinate attributes, but that is a bit of a palaver.

Comment: Maybe this? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30581/how-can-i-move-diagrams If not, please ask a new question :-)