# Move overlapping pie charts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, chart

I'm referring to a question I found here ([How can I move diagrams?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30581/how-can-i-move-diagrams)) about pie charts in QGIS. I too would like to move some pie charts because they are overlapping each other. I tried to follow the instructions on the link, but didn't understand the approach properly. 
I was able to create a dbf with the centroids of the polygons, however, i am not sure if the centroids were of the polygons of the layer OR the pie charts. Also, I did not know how to move the diagrams with the dfb-file I had created.

I'm using QGIS 2.18.3. (Las Palmas).