# QGIS Making population pyramids as diagrams

Tags: qgis, position, diagram, translation

I'm trying to make age-gender pyramids as diagrams placed over centroids of map shapes.
Using horizontal histograms I can create the right hand side:
[image]

And by switching the direction of the bars (from another layer), I can make the left hand side:
[image]

When both layers are visible, and diagrams are positioned "over centroid" in both layers, I get this result:

[image]

I would like to offset the right bars to the right, and the left bars to the left, by placing the y-axis of the diagram on the centroid, so I try to displace the diagrams like this:

[image]

However, the diagram position does not change.

How can I offset a diagram in the x-axis by 50% of its own width?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a simple solution for this - diagrams tend to be not so flexible. You have the option to manually shift individual diagrams using `Move a Label or Diagram`, see https://www.igismap.com/pin-unpin-labels-move-labels-and-diagrams-resize-labels-of-layer-using-qgis-3-2-1 Maybe this here can help as well: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30617/88814 I would create the bars using geometry generator, where you have the full flexibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved! (very hacky though)

If my data is like

[image]

then the diagram will be centered on the midpoint of the widest bar.
However, if I make all the values negative and create one (meaningless) column with a small positive value (1)

[image]

then the diagram will be centred on its own y-axis (minus 1 pixel or so).

[image]

This is what the assigned attributes for the diagram look like:
[image]

Comment: Great! Can you explain how you did the settings in the placement tab of the diagrams? This works rather buggy in my case: when I want horizontal bars, it only works if I first close the layer properties and open it again and select it a second time. I was also able to get near to your solution, but not fully, so I would appreciate to learn more about it.

Comment: Look at my result: the red dot is the centroid: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UL9Z.png In some cases it works nice (red arrows), in other cases not at all (red circles). Also not sure where/how you used the `fake` field for placement.

Comment: Got it: QGIS uses the centroid of the **visible** part of the polygon - so where polygons are partially outside the map canvas, the centroid shifts inside the polygon towards the center of the canvas. A great workaround for a missing feature. Would be nice to have more flexible settings for diagrams.

Comment: @Babel the offsetting of the centroid where the polygon overlaps the canvas isn’t an issue for me, so long as the two sides of the pyramid sit with their vertical axes on the same point.Have you tried increasing the Priority slider to 100%?

Comment: Yes, I tried to increase the priority slide, however this has no influence on the result. Where/how did you apply the `fake` field?

Comment: As though it were another age grouping. See updated answer with assigned attributes settings. I coloured "fake" to make it match the background as I understand transparency is not possible in a diagram.

Comment: Perfect, that's it! Probably as close as you can get to an ideal solution without coding.

Comment: I'd be happy to code, but haven't explored writing functions in QGIS yet. If you have any suggestions of useful tutorials to get started, that would be great - there are several other diagram types I'd like to develop, maybe as plugins.

Comment: I found a great video about making multiple diagram types (in Italian): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDcyGNqsuSI