# Two diagrams on same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, diagram

I want to create two stacked bars next to each other for different polygons in a layer (see example with one stacked bar attached). Since I could not actually create two diagramms for the same layer, I've tried to duplicate the layer, but failed to align the position of both bars since they appear to depend on the height of the graph. I'm using QGIS 3.16.

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392345/88814